# Owl carousel slider custom post type not work correctly

Tags: jquery, wordpress, tabs, slider, carousel

I have tabs with taxonomies WordPress. In click on each tab, we display their posts in the carousel.

In my case just the first tab, the carousel works correctly, in the others tabs the carousel doesn't work .

I started from this link : https://codepen.io/gatoledo1/pen/zYYEazv

I want to display posts in caroussel in click the tab . any idea please for this problem

[image]

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

<style>
    ul.nav.nav-tabs.filters li span.active {
        color: #ff6944;
    }

    #news-slider {
        margin-top: 80px;
    }

    .post-slide {
        background: #fff;
        margin: 20px 15px 20px;
        border-radius: 15px;
        padding-top: 1px;
        box-shadow: 0px 14px 22px -9px #bbcbd8;
    }

    .post-slide .post-img {
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
        border-radius: 10px;
        margin: -12px 15px 8px 15px;
        margin-left: -10px;
    }

    .post-slide .post-img img {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        transform: scale(1, 1);
        transition: transform 0.2s linear;
    }

    .post-slide:hover .post-img img {
        transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
    }

    .post-slide .over-layer {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        opacity: 0;
        background: linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(6, 190, 244, 0.75) 0%, rgba(45, 112, 253, 0.6) 100%);
        transition: all 0.50s linear;
    }

    .post-slide:hover .over-layer {
        opacity: 1;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    .post-slide .over-layer i {
        position: relative;
        top: 45%;
        text-align: center;
        display: block;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 25px;
    }

    .post-slide .post-content {
        background: #fff;
        padding: 2px 20px 40px;
        border-radius: 15px;
    }

    .post-slide .post-title a {
        font-size: 15px;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #333;
        display: inline-block;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    }

    .post-slide .post-title a:hover {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #3498db;
    }

    .post-slide .post-description {
        line-height: 24px;
        color: #808080;
        margin-bottom: 25px;
    }

    .post-slide .post-date {
        color: #a9a9a9;
        font-size: 14px;
    }

    .post-slide .post-date i {
        font-size: 20px;
        margin-right: 8px;
        color: #CFDACE;
    }

    .post-slide .read-more {
        padding: 7px 20px;
        float: right;
        font-size: 12px;
        background: #2196F3;
        color: #ffffff;
        box-shadow: 0px 10px 20px -10px #1376c5;
        border-radius: 25px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }

    .post-slide .read-more:hover {
        background: #3498db;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #fff;
    }

    .owl-controls .owl-buttons {
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 20px;
    }

    .owl-controls .owl-buttons .owl-prev {
        background: #fff;
        position: absolute;
        top: -13%;
        left: 15px;
        padding: 0 18px 0 15px;
        border-radius: 50px;
        box-shadow: 3px 14px 25px -10px #92b4d0;
        transition: background 0.5s ease 0s;
    }

    .owl-controls .owl-buttons .owl-next {
        background: #fff;
        position: absolute;
        top: -13%;
        right: 15px;
        padding: 0 15px 0 18px;
        border-radius: 50px;
        box-shadow: -3px 14px 25px -10px #92b4d0;
        transition: background 0.5s ease 0s;
    }

    .owl-controls .owl-buttons .owl-prev:after,
    .owl-controls .owl-buttons .owl-next:after {
        content: "\f104";
        font-family: FontAwesome;
        color: #333;
        font-size: 30px;
    }

    .owl-controls .owl-buttons .owl-next:after {
        content: "\f105";
    }

    .post-annee,
    .post-title,
    .post-prix {
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width:1280px) {
        .post-slide .post-content {
            padding: 0px 15px 25px 15px;
        }
    }
</style>



<div class="container tab">

    <?php
    echo '<ul class="nav menu-filter nav-tabs filters" role="tablist">';

    $args = [
        'taxonomy' => 'type_vehicle',
        'hide_empty' => 0,
        'orderby' => 'id',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'parent' => '0',
    ];
    $categories = get_categories($args);

    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        echo '<li class="ongnels-inactifs pays-filters">
                    <span data-href="' .
            $category->slug .
            '" id="' .
            $category->slug .
            '" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" class="ongnels-inactif">    
                        ' .
            $category->name .
            '
                    </span>
                    
                </li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';

    echo '<div class="investors-content pays-cards " >';

    foreach ($categories as $category) {

        echo '<div class="tab-pane" id="' . $category->slug . '">';
        $catslug = $category->slug;

        $the_query = new WP_Query([
            'post_type' => 'vehicules',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'tax_query' => [
                [
                    'taxonomy' => 'type_vehicle',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => [$catslug],
                    'operator' => 'IN',
                ],
            ],
        ]);
    ?>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">

                    <div id="news-slider" class="owl-carousel">


                        <?php while ($the_query->have_posts()) :
                            $the_query->the_post(); ?>



                            <div class="post-slide">
                                <div class="post-img">
                                    <?php the_post_thumbnail('single-post-thumbnail'); ?>
                                </div>
                                <div class="post-content">
                                    <span class="post-annee">
                                        <?php the_field('annee', $post->ID); ?>
                                    </span>
                                    <span class="post-title">
                                        <?php the_title(); ?>
                                    </span>
                                    <span class="post-prix">
                                        <?php the_field('prix_mois', $post->ID); ?>
                                    </span>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 km"> <?php the_field('kilometrage', $post->ID); ?></div>
                                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 boite"> <?php the_field('boite', $post->ID); ?></div>
                                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 gazoil"> <?php the_field('gazoil', $post->ID); ?></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="read-more">Réserver</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>


                        <?php
                        endwhile; ?>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>


    <?php echo '</div>';
    }

    echo '</div>';
    ?>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('span#voiture').addClass("active");
            $("#news-slider").owlCarousel({
                items: 1,
                itemsDesktop: [1199, 3],
                itemsDesktopSmall: [980, 2],
                itemsMobile: [600, 1],
                navigation: true,
                navigationText: ["", ""],
                pagination: true,
                autoPlay: true
            });
        });
        $("div#voiture").css({
            "display": "block"
        });
        $("div#van").css({
            "display": "none"
        });
        $("div#camion").css({
            "display": "none"
        });
        $("div#autres").css({
            "display": "none"
        });


        $(".nav-tabs li>span").on("click", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var id = $(this).attr("data-href");
            $(".investors-content .tab-pane").each(function() {
                $(this).hide();
                if ($(this).attr("id") == id) {
                    $(this).show();
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: same ids in tabs. IDs must be uniques

Comment: Hi @Shozabjaveed, thank you , what de you mean please